# ASP.Net IsAuthenticated returns true after cookie is expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, httpcontext

I have an asp.net single page web application.

When the user enters to me web application , it gets a login screen with username password and I make an ajax call for authentication:

```
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                    "CookieName",
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
                    true,
                    "data",
                    FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        // Encrypt the ticket.
        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

Before any ajax call I check if the request and the user are authenticated:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
             //do something
    }
}
```

but when the cookie is expired, I still get "true" for both conditions.

Why? Is it because I make an ajax call? 
Should I check if the cookie expired before every call instead of using IsAuthenticated?

Comment: How often are you making the AJAX call? What kind of AJAX call? How did you check that the cookie is expired?

Comment: Hi @Alexander I have a lot of ajax calls in order to bring data relevant for the specific user, that's why I have to check that the user is authenticated

Comment: In what intervals are they called? I suspect that "sliding expiration" is preventing the authentication from expiring. That's why I asked how you checked if the cookie was expired?

Comment: Are you sure your Ajax calls are not cached by the browser so that actually it reads the value from the browser's cache?

Comment: @Alexander I use this code: HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];  FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value); and then I check IsExpired of authTicket

Comment: @WiktorZychla good point! I will check it out :) thanks..

Comment: Yes, but I meant when you are debugging your problem, did you check if the cookie actually expired? By looking at the cookie itself, via Notepad or the browser. Trying to find out if you are certain your cookie IS expired, or if you are just expecting it to be.